# Can the norm of a convex combination of vectors be greater than the norm of their sum?

Tags: normed-spaces, average

Can the norm of a convex combination of vectors be greater than the norm of their sum?

Or is it always the case that:

$|| \sum_i w_i x_i || \leq \sum_i w_i  \;|| \sum_i x_i  || $

(for positive $w_i$)

(with the standard L2-norm).

Proof or counterexample would be great.  I'm also curious if it holds for other norms.

Comment: from the absolute homogeneity and triangle inequality follows that every norm is convex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct for any norm. Note that for any norm the inequality
$$\left\|\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i x_i\right\| \le \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n |\lambda_i| \left\|x_i\right\|$$

holds for any linear combination. This is easy to prove via induction, using the triangle inequality and absolute homogeneity of the norm.

In your case the $w_i$ are all nonnegative, so $|w_i| = w_i$ and the equality in your question holds true.